# initial migration with ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When I run my initial migration I get a "new.html.erb" file for each of my models. Its a very simple looking form, but the "new.html.erb" contains just the following code..

```
<h1>New city</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', cities_path %>
```

Now I want to modify this page, but I dont really understand whats going on here, where in the project this 'form' is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is located under `app/views/cities/_form.html.erb`.

I strongly suggest you to read [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) before start working with ruby - it will give you a better understanding of how things works.

Since Rais works on **convention over configuration**, you will have a bad time trying to figure out everything by yourself. However, once you are used to the conventions, your will have a very fast development speed.

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder where your new view is located.